# Ember js multiple levels deep namespaces

Tags: ember.js

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(){
        this.controllerFor('App.Namespace1.Object1').set('model', model);
    }    
});

App.Namespace1.Object1Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

*This works*

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(){
        this.controllerFor('App.Object1').set('model', model);
    }    
});

App.Object1Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

This is the error I see.

```
Error: assertion failed: You are trying to look up a controller that you did 
not define, and for which Ember does not know the model.

This is not a controller for a route, so you must explicitly define the controller 
(Minerva.Namespace1Object1Controller) or pass a model as the second parameter to 
`controllerFor`, so that Ember knows which type of controller to create for you.
http://localhost:8090/EmberApplication/js/vendor/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js
Line 53
```

Does EmberJS support namespaces that are multiple levels deep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! I just deleted my old answer because a close inspection of the code in `Ember.Resolver` reveals that the following should be possible:

```
this.controllerFor('App/Namespace1/object1')
```

(convention is to refer to controllers in the context of a route in the lowercase)

Comment: Fair warning: while the code currently supports doing this, other parts assume only one namespace (for instance, the auto-capitalization would turn `app/namespace1` into `App.namespace1`) so this isn't necessarily guaranteed to always work.

Comment: Of what use is one lever deep namespacing ?!! Thanks for your help though